# Can one access the Excel Filter function on MS Office 365 ProPlus?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not able to access the Filter function on Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus. Is there a way to do this?

From what I see it's only available using MS Insiders or Google Sheets.

Comment: That's a Q&A within two of your own sentences =)

Comment: Patience Grasshopper.  It has appeared in my Microsoft Office 365 (not insider; not proPlus).  So it should eventually show up in yours.